# Open .log file with OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to open text from a `.log` file in SQL Server?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'..\30-09-2014.log', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
```

This code returns content in binary format, I want text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'..\30-09-2014.log', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Document;

BLOB to CLOB OR NCLOB
```